# Difference between adding and appending to a list in Python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between LIST.append(1) and LIST = LIST + [1] (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638486/what-is-the-difference-between-list-append1-and-list-list-1-python)

I have a doubt on how parameters are passed to functions and their mutability, especially in the case of lists.

Consider the following...

```
def add_list(p):
    p = p + [1]

def append_list(p):
   p.append(1)

p = [1, 2, 3]

add_list(p)
print p

append_list(p)
print p
```

The output I get is...

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 1]
```

Why does the original list change when I append to it in a function, but is unchanged if I use the operator +?

Comment: Appending mutates. Adding copies.

Comment: Short Answer: `append()` changes the list **in-place** and `+` returns a new list, it doesn't affects the original list at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assignment operator within a function creates a new local variable.
In the *add_list* function your *p* is local variable.