# Python build a list by two different methods

Tags: python, list, append

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between LIST.append(1) and LIST = LIST + [1] (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638486/what-is-the-difference-between-list-append1-and-list-list-1-python)

I'm new to Python and new to programming. I followed the book ThinkPython and here is one thing I can't get straight.

> Exercise 10.7 Write a function that reads the file words.txt and builds a list with one element per word. Write two versions of this function, one using the append method and the other using the idiom t = t + [x]. Which one takes longer to run? Why?

I tried the two methods and found the later one (t=t+[x]) took much longer time than append method. Here is my first question, why would this happen?

I changed the line t=t+[x] to t+=[x] just for no reason only to find this revised version take almost the same time as the append method. I thought t=t+[x] is equal to t+=[x], apparently they are not. Why?

BTW: I tried search Google using python += as key words but it seems Google won't take += as a key word even I put a quotation mark to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
t = t + [x]
```

takes `t`, concatenates with `[x]` (calling `t`'s method [`__add__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__)), which creates a new list, which is then named `t`.

```
t += [x]
```

calls the `t`'s method [`__iadd__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) which works directly on the list itself. There is no extra list created.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. my post is a duplicate of the one you linked. I should have done a deeper search.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know, that the [**add**](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) method results creating a new object, while append() just *modifies* the existing object, thus resulting in better performance.

As for the second question, knowing the above, you may [find out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/what-does-plus-equals-do-in-python) what the '+=' or 'plus equals' operator is equivalent to in python and therefore behave differently to '+' operator.

You might also want to check out [this link](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/458604-difference-__iadd__-__add__) which explains the difference between **add** and **iadd** methods which are being called in your example and perhaps [this one](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) as well to establish your knowledge.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the very good link on the python.org. It does clear my confusion.