# Difference between variants of code adding an element to a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

```
L = [1,2,3,4]

L.append(13) # (1)
L = L + [13] # (2)
```

What is difference in above statements?

Comment: There isn't really a difference, though in the latter it seems you are unnecessarily creating a new list `[13]`

Comment: And `+=` is different again

Comment: There is a huge difference, and `+=` is *not* different from the last line.

Comment: Are you asking the difference in the performance?

Comment: @Aerovistae, really?

Comment: @Aerovistae: `+=` is different, try it ;)

Comment: I just did. It's not different. `L += [13]` is shorthand for `L = L + [13]`.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725782/in-python-what-is-the-difference-between-append-and and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638486/what-is-the-difference-between-list-append1-and-list-list-1-python

Comment: @Aerovistae, It's different in that it extends the existing list and doesn't create a new one, unlike `L = L + [13]`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen INTERESTING!!! Didn't know *that.*

Comment: To check the difference use `print(id(L))` on `L` after each command.

Answer (score 5):

`L.append(13)` appends 13 to an existing list.

`L = L + [13]` creates a new list.

Comment: This is (at the time of this comment) the only answer that addresses the difference between mutating a list and assigning a new list value to the original name.

Comment: I had forgotten to mention that. Thx for reminder.

Answer (score 2):

`L.append(13)` adds a single item, the int `13`, to the end of the list.

`L = L + [13]` adds every item in a secondary list to the end of the first list. So you could have written `L = L + [12, 4, 13]` and it would add all three.

Moreover, `append` adds `13` to the end of an existing list....in the computer's memory, `L` is still the same list, just with a new item added into it. But whenever you use the `=` operator*, *you're creating something new.* So `L = L + [13]` is creating a new list in the computer's memory, assigning it the name `L` and filling it with the contents of the old `L` concatenated with the list `[13]`.

*If you do `var1 = var2`, however, it's not creating something new but rather assigning the name `var1` to point to the same place in memory as `var2`.

Comment: "But whenever you use the = operator, you're creating something new."  This glosses over the difference between rebinding and mutation, and makes it seem like `M = L` will create a new list in the computer's memory.